# BlockInput from DLL in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, dll, cmd, user32, rundll32

I am trying to create a simple batch script to run in windows that wait for 20 minutes and then block the inputs by a minute.

```
TIMEOUT 1200
rundll32.exe User32.dll, BlockInput 1
TIMEOUT 60
rundll32.exe User32.dll, BlockInput 0
```

But it looks like according to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32) "Rundll32 can only call functions from a DLL explicitly written to be called by Rundll32."

Can rundll32 run BlockInput from User32.dll?

If it is not possible, how could I access the function using only native windows software? (Powershell, VBScript, JScript, etc)

Comment: `BlockInput(BOOL fBlockIt)` so Rundll32 passes a window handle in parameter 1.